# Find a row meeting conditions at most in n next rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
    close   low     max_close   higher_low
0     2      1        True        False
1     3      4        False       True
2     1      2        True        False
3     0      3        False       False
4     5      2        False       True
5     4      5        False       True
6     3      3        True        False
7     6      7        False       True
```

and could be created with the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'close': [2, 3, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 6], 
        'low': [1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7], 
        'max_close': [True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False], 
        'higher_low': [False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True]
    }
)
```

For any row with a `True` value in the *max_close* column, I want to find the first row in the next rows where the value in the *higher_low* column is `True` and the value in the *low* column is greater than the value in the *close* column and also this row must be at most in the next 2 rows after the row where the value in *max_close* column was `True`.

So the output should be :

```py
    close   low     max_close   higher_low
1     3      4        False        True
7     6      7        False        True
```

(Index 4 is not in the output because in this row: `low < close`. Also, index 5 is not in the output because it's three rows after index 2, while we have a condition that it should be at most in the next 2 rows.)

Also, it's my priority not to use any for-loops in the code.

Have you any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
lookup = 2

indices = []
for i in range(1, lookup+1):
    if i > 1:
        tmp = df.loc[(df[df['max_close']].loc[:-(i-1)].index+i)]
    else:
        tmp = df.loc[(df[df['max_close']].index+i)]
    tmp_ind = tmp[(tmp['higher_low']) & (tmp['low']>tmp['close'])].index
    indices += tmp_ind.tolist()
df.loc[set(indices)]
```

**Output**

```
   close  low  max_close  higher_low
1      3    4      False        True
7      6    7      False        True
```

Answer (score 1):

Create virtual groups from `max_close` column then keep the 3 first rows (1 row for `max_close` and the 2 following). Finally, filter out on your 2 conditions:

```
out = (df.groupby(df['max_close'].cumsum()).head(3)
         .query("higher_low & (close < low)"))
print(out)

# Output
   close  low  max_close  higher_low
1      3    4      False        True
7      6    7      False        True
```